# How to save xls attachment as xlsx from outlook - pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I receive a batch email containing a xls file, I have a script that searches my Outlook inbox for that email and extracts the attachment. I would like to save the file as an xlsx instead of it's current format xls.

I have tried to amend the file name in the SaveAsFile attachment method to include x at the end - attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(file_home_path, new_file_name)+"x") - this did save the file as an xlsx but the file got corrupted and I couldn't open it.

Are there any other attachment methods that allow the file extension to be amended at source?

```py
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

file_home_path = "C:/Desktop"

for message in messages:
    if message.Subject == 'subject_to_search_for':
        attachments = message.Attachments
        for attachment in attachments:
            new_file_name = 'required_file_{}.xls'.format(now)
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(file_home_path, new_file_name))
            break
        message.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

My work around is below.

```py
os.chdir(file_home_path)
excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(new_file_name)
wb.SaveAs(new_file_name+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()
excel.Application.Quit()
```